# Поле телефон битрикс 24

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Покупатель делает заказ на сайте битрикс, заказ прилетает в crm Битрикс 24, из заказа передается только имя и емейл, но телефон, коментарий к заказу и адрес не подгружаются.

Как исправить проблему?

Comment: Значит вы что-то не донастроили. Т.к. если клиент заполнил в заказе телефон, то он передается. Это штатная возможность. Настраивается там же где и соответствие данных для отправки в 1С.

Answer (score 1):

Магазин - Настройки - Интеграция с 1С там все настройки